# In creating `Today' column in ASPNETDB.MDF getdate() will not be constant

Tags: asp.net, database, sql-server-2005

I have set a column named `Today' in ASPNETDB.MDF where I want to input current datetime only. I m using getdate() but It can not update automatically update present time. 
Suppose an user created his/her account on 1/5/2013 9:24:08 PM, then 'Today' column display the 1/5/2013 9:24:08 PM, fine, but it set constantly, I want 'Today' column will be filled with present time like at the time of 1/7/2013 11:24:08 PM, 'Today' column display 1/7/2013 11:24:08 PM in every row.

I will be thankful if anyone help me.

N:B: I M A BEGINNER, I THINK THERE ARE VARIOUS SOLVED THREAD HERE, I ALREADY LOOKED IN THAT BUT GETTING CONFUSED WHICH ONE WILL BE FIT MY PROBLEM. SO THIS QUESTION IS VEXATIOUS THEN I M SORRY.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.aspnet_Membership_CreateUser
@ApplicationName                        nvarchar(256),
@UserName                               nvarchar(256),
@Password                               nvarchar(128),
@PasswordSalt                           nvarchar(128),
@Email                                  nvarchar(256),
@PasswordQuestion                       nvarchar(256),
@PasswordAnswer                         nvarchar(128),
@IsApproved                             bit,
@DaysLeft                               numeric(18, 0),
@CurrentTimeUtc                         datetime,
@CreateDate                             datetime = NULL,
@ExpiryDate                             datetime = NULL,
@UniqueEmail                            int      = 0,
@PasswordFormat                         int      = 0,
@UserId                                 uniqueidentifier OUTPUT
```

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ApplicationId uniqueidentifier
    SELECT  @ApplicationId = NULL

```
DECLARE @NewUserId uniqueidentifier
SELECT @NewUserId = NULL

DECLARE @IsLockedOut bit
SET @IsLockedOut = 0

DECLARE @LastLockoutDate  datetime
SET @LastLockoutDate = CONVERT( datetime, '17540101', 112 )

DECLARE @FailedPasswordAttemptCount int
SET @FailedPasswordAttemptCount = 0

DECLARE @FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart  datetime
SET @FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart = CONVERT( datetime, '17540101', 112 )

DECLARE @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount int
SET @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount = 0

DECLARE @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart  datetime
SET @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart = CONVERT( datetime, '17540101', 112 )

DECLARE @NewUserCreated bit
DECLARE @ReturnValue   int
SET @ReturnValue = 0

DECLARE @ErrorCode     int
SET @ErrorCode = 0

DECLARE @TranStarted   bit
SET @TranStarted = 0

IF( @@TRANCOUNT = 0 )
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SET @TranStarted = 1
END
ELSE
    SET @TranStarted = 0

EXEC dbo.aspnet_Applications_CreateApplication @ApplicationName, @ApplicationId OUTPUT

IF( @@ERROR <> 0 )
BEGIN
    SET @ErrorCode = -1
    GOTO Cleanup
END

SET @CreateDate = DATEADD(hour, +6, @CurrentTimeUtc)
SET @ExpiryDate = DATEADD(day,365, @CreateDate)
SET @DaysLeft = DATEDIFF(day, @CurrentTimeUtc, @ExpiryDate);

SELECT  @NewUserId = UserId FROM dbo.aspnet_Users WHERE LOWER(@UserName) = LoweredUserName AND @ApplicationId = ApplicationId
IF ( @NewUserId IS NULL )
BEGIN
    SET @NewUserId = @UserId
    EXEC @ReturnValue = dbo.aspnet_Users_CreateUser @ApplicationId, @UserName, 0, @CreateDate, @NewUserId OUTPUT
    SET @NewUserCreated = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @NewUserCreated = 0
    IF( @NewUserId <> @UserId AND @UserId IS NOT NULL )
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorCode = 6
        GOTO Cleanup
    END
END

IF( @@ERROR <> 0 )
BEGIN
    SET @ErrorCode = -1
    GOTO Cleanup
END

IF( @ReturnValue = -1 )
BEGIN
    SET @ErrorCode = 10
    GOTO Cleanup
END

IF ( EXISTS ( SELECT UserId
              FROM   dbo.aspnet_Membership
              WHERE  @NewUserId = UserId ) )
BEGIN
    SET @ErrorCode = 6
    GOTO Cleanup
END

SET @UserId = @NewUserId

IF (@UniqueEmail = 1)
BEGIN
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM  dbo.aspnet_Membership m WITH ( UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK )
                WHERE ApplicationId = @ApplicationId AND LoweredEmail = LOWER(@Email)))
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorCode = 7
        GOTO Cleanup
    END
END

IF (@NewUserCreated = 0)
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.aspnet_Users
    SET    LastActivityDate = @CreateDate
    WHERE  @UserId = UserId
    IF( @@ERROR <> 0 )
    BEGIN
        SET @ErrorCode = -1
        GOTO Cleanup
    END
END

INSERT INTO dbo.aspnet_Membership
            ( ApplicationId,
              UserId,
              Password,
              PasswordSalt,
              Email,
              LoweredEmail,
              PasswordQuestion,
              PasswordAnswer,
              PasswordFormat,
              IsApproved,
              IsLockedOut,
              CreateDate,
              ExpiryDate,
              DaysLeft,
              LastLoginDate,
              LastPasswordChangedDate,
              LastLockoutDate,
              FailedPasswordAttemptCount,
              FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart,
              FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount,
              FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart )
     VALUES ( @ApplicationId,
              @UserId,
              @Password,
              @PasswordSalt,
              @Email,
              LOWER(@Email),
              @PasswordQuestion,
              @PasswordAnswer,
              @PasswordFormat,
              @IsLockedOut,
              @IsLockedOut,
              @CreateDate,
              @ExpiryDate,
              @DaysLeft,
              @CreateDate,
              @CreateDate,
              @LastLockoutDate,
              @FailedPasswordAttemptCount,
              @FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart,
              @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount,
              @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart )

IF( @@ERROR <> 0 )
BEGIN
    SET @ErrorCode = -1
    GOTO Cleanup
END

IF( @TranStarted = 1 )
BEGIN
    SET @TranStarted = 0
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END

RETURN 0
```

Cleanup:

```
IF( @TranStarted = 1 )
BEGIN
    SET @TranStarted = 0
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END

RETURN @ErrorCode
```

END

Comment: It sounds like you want every row in your table to display the current datetime? I'm not sure why you would want this, but you might get more people trying to help you if you post sample data and tables and show an example of the output you require.

Comment: CreateDate-  ExpiryDate-  Today-   DaysLeft for Expiration
1/5/20013- 1/5/20014     1/7/2013  -363
Here I want a function today's current date that will not be constant and (ExpiryDate-Today)= DaysLeft for Expiration

Answer (score 2):

> I want 'Today' column will be filled with present time ... in every
>   row.

Use `getdate()` directly in your query and use [`datediff()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) to calculate a difference between dates.

```
select Column1,
       Column2,
       getdate() as Today,
       datediff(day, getdate(), ExpiryDate) as DaysLeft
from YourTable
```

It makes no sense to hold the current date and time in a table since it is constantly changing and can easily be queried using `getdate()`.

Comment: Thanks sir, 
I m trying ==
but in stored procedure where can I input this function and How is the function, if you suggest details. in stored procedure there is an object named dbo.aspnet_Membership_CreateUser
Mytable @Today           datetime

Comment: @user1954976 Can you update your question with the stored procedure along with a description of what you want it to do and what is not working as expected?

Comment: @user1954976 You have added a stored procedure that saves the data to a table. I mean that you should **not** store `Today` in the table. Have you added that yourself? Instead you should use the function `getdate()` when you query the table if you really need the current date and time in a column in the resultset.

Comment: yes, I have added

"""It makes no sense to hold the current date and time in a table since it is constantly changing and can easily be queried using getdate()"""

Then what will be my @DaysLeft column function here that I want to put in DaysLeft column the difference between Today and Expiryday
Please suggest

Comment: @user1954976 If `DaysLeft` is calculated from `ExpiryDate` and `getdate()` then you should not store `DaysLeft` either. Calculate when you need it. Something like this: `select datediff(day, getdate(), ExpiryDate) as DaysLeft from dbo.aspnet_Membership`

Comment: Thanks brother, but if you dont mind, can you tell me where I can put your function
=======
select Column1,
       Column2,
       getdate() as Today,
       datediff(day, getdate(), ExpiryDate) as DaysLeft
from YourTable
=====
I already edited my procedure in this post, but when I try to create an user it show error message 
----------
Procedure or function 'aspnet_Membership_CreateUser' expects parameter '@DaysLeft', which was not supplied.
--------------------Whats the wrong in my function??
in above code Which is Column1, or column2,

Comment: @user1954976 You should not store days left in the table. Remove `@DaysLeft` from the parameter list in the stored procedure and in the insert statement and from the table definition. You should calculate the value for days left when you query your table. The SP you have in your question is for saving to the table not for querying the table. The query I have provided in my answer is a sample query that shows how you can use `getdate()` and `datediff()` in a query to calculate `DaysLeft`.